# JMeter JSR223 preprocessor cannot parse JSON with placeholder

Tags: jmeter

In a JMeter test plan I need to do the following...

`Generate TID` puts a more or less random number into `vars.tid`.

The `Calculate checksum` preprocessor calculates a checksum which is put into `vars.checksum`. This checksum, however, depends on the `tid` and further data (`var1` and `var2`) from the JSON payload in `Send request`.

**Example for the JSON body**

```json
{
  "event": {
    "checksum": "${checksum}",
    "tid": ${tid},
  },
  "data": {
    "var1": "value1",
    "var2": "value2
  }
}
```

**`Calculate checksum`**

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
 
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

def requestBodyString = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
def json = jsonSlurper.parseText(requestBodyString)

def tid = vars.get('tid')
def checkusm = calculateChecksum(tid, json.var1, json.var2)

vars.put('checksum', checksum)
```

Now, the `JsonSluper` seems to no actually parse the content because of `"tid": ${tid}` which is not valid JSON. As a consequence, the `checksum` won't get replaced before sending the request.

Do you have any ideas how to work around this?

[image: Generate TID]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to resolve the "placeholders" and replace them with the relevant variables values you need to use [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) in conjunction with [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) and pass the result to the JsonSlurper:

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)